# How to print all the port's status with nmap?

Tags: nmap

I use nmap in order to test an external embedded device. 
Nmap gives different output/results when the port range increase.

For example:

```
nmap -sT -p 1-10 10.39.123.456
```

//print all the port's status

```
nmap -sT -p 1-1000 10.39.123456
```

//nmap show only the open port

Is possible to avoid this ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Nmap hides "uninteresting" port statuses (usually `closed` and `filtered`) when there are too many of them; it prints a line like `Not shown: 987 closed ports` in this case. You can increase the threshold where Nmap decides to collapse uninteresting statuses by increasing the verbosity (`-v`) or debug (`-d`) levels. At debug level 3 (`-d3`), all ports will be shown regardless of state.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this 
nmap -sT -p- 10.39.123.456

Comment: Hi, no this print only the open port.